# Multiple definitions of my template class

Tags: c++, templates, linker

In my library, I have several `initialize()` and `cleanup()` functions, for different modules it depends on.

To make this part more safe to use, I decided to follow the RAII rule and built up an `Initializer` **template class**, that takes two functions as parameters:

```
// initializer.hpp (include guards omitted)

template <void initialize(), void cleanup()>
class Initializer
{
  // Does something, but that's not relevant
};
```

Now, in my `xml.hpp` file I have this:

```
// xml.hpp (include guards omitted)

namespace xml
{       
  void initialize();
  void cleanup();

  typename ::Initializer<&initialize, &cleanup> Initializer;
}
```

This compiles fine but fails on linking because several files include `xml.hpp` and gcc complains that there are multiple definitions for `xml::Initializer`.

What can I do to solve this ?

Comment: `typename` looks out of place here, or is your posted code incomplete? gcc says "error: using ‘typename’ outside of template".

Comment: @Charles Bailey: In my place it compiled, but it is indeed an error. I just changed it to "typedef" (which I meant in the first place) and all the link errors are gone... I need more coffee ! Thanks for that. Can you add an answer so I accept it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
namespace xml
{       
  void initialize();
  void cleanup();

  typename ::Initializer<&initialize, &cleanup> Initializer;
}
```

`typename` is illegal here, it is only allowed in template definitions. You meant `typedef`!

```
namespace xml
{       
  void initialize();
  void cleanup();

  typedef ::Initializer<&initialize, &cleanup> Initializer;
}
```

Comment: Indeed I meant `typedef` ;) Thanks for noticing it !

Answer (score 2):

```
typename ::Initializer<&initialize, &cleanup> Initializer;
```

This is an explicit instantiation. Please put it in one and only one translation unit

Comment: As @Charles Bailey pointed out, it was a stupid typo... I meant `typedef`. Still, thanks. I just need more coffee I guess... +1 ;)

Comment: But I guess the error was about multiple definitions. If it was a typename issues, it would be a syntax error. I am confused

Comment: My compiler didn't complain about a syntax error. It would have been easier to spot, indeed. My question includes a simplified example of my code, perhaps this is the reason why it passed compilation.

Answer (score 0):

include your xml.hpp code inside these macros

```
#ifndef XML_HPP
#define XML_HPP

// Include code here

#endif
```

Comment: Thanks but I already have include guards. I just omitted them for simplicity's sake.